# Jquery get the title Attribute, problem

Tags: jquery, attributes

The title attribute didn't shows. 
If you have a tip using another attribute type, I just need to get this data to put in the div, let me know please.

```
$(function() {

    var offsetY = 10;

    $('a').hover(function(e) {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('<div id="PopRoll">'+title+'</div')
        .css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
        .appendTo('body');
    }, function() {
        $('#PopRoll').remove();
    });


});
```

In this href:

```
<p ><a href="#" title="text" class="JobLink">More Information</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your div structure working correctly and as you want it? You're missing a `<` in there =) Other then those two, it looks correct. Make sure your Z-indexes are there too!